# Java Program - Word Statistics

Tags: java, count, statistics, cpu-word, keyword

I have created a Java program that goes out and returns search results from various social media API's based on a keyword text file and writes the returned results to another text file.

I am now trying to have another class separate class that will scan the search results text file and return statistics on how many times the 'keywords' were found in the search results. I am basically trying to run the search against the keywords.txt file.

I have been trying to get the below code to work but I can only get it to return all words, rather than just those from the keywords.txt file.

I have tried to get an input StreamReader to work but to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

```
package search;

import java.util.*; // Provides TreeMap, Iterator, Scanner
import java.io.*; // Provides FileReader, FileNotFoundException

public class SearchResults
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        TreeMap<String, Integer> frequencyData = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
        readWordFile(frequencyData); 
        printAllCounts(frequencyData);
    }

    public static int getCount(String word, TreeMap<String, Integer> frequencyData)
    {
        if (frequencyData.containsKey(word))
        { // The word has occurred before, so get its count from the map
            return frequencyData.get(word); // Auto-unboxed
        }
        else
        { // No occurrences of this word
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public static void printAllCounts(TreeMap<String, Integer> frequencyData)
    {
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(" Occurrences Word");

        for(String word : frequencyData.keySet())
        {
            System.out.printf("%15d %s\n", frequencyData.get(word), word);
        }

        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------");
    } 

    public static void readWordFile(TreeMap<String, Integer> frequencyData)
    {
        Scanner wordFile;
        String word; // A word read from the file
        Integer count; // The number of occurrences of the word

        try
        {
            wordFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("SearchResults.txt"));
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.err.println(e);
            return;
        }

        while (wordFile.hasNext())
        {
            // Read the next word and get rid of the end-of-line marker if needed:
            word = wordFile.next();

            // Get the current count of this word, add one, and then store the new count:
            count = getCount(word, frequencyData) + 1;
            frequencyData.put(word, count);
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly do you perhaps want to add another if statement that checks if count != 0 and only then add it to your frequencyData map?

Comment: What exactly have you tried? There is zero lines in that code dealing with keywords.txt. It sounds very suspicious when you state that you are trying to get it to work without having a single line that would be the evidence of that.

Answer (score 1):

There, I cleaned up your code and added filtering by all the keywords found in keywords.txt.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  printAllCounts(
    readWordFile("SearchResults.txt", loadKeywords("keywords.txt")));
}

private static Map<String, Integer> readWordFile(
  String fname, Set<String> keywords) throws FileNotFoundException
{
  final Map<String, Integer> frequencyData = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
  for (Scanner wordFile = new Scanner(new FileReader(fname)); 
    wordFile.hasNext();) 
  {
    final String word = wordFile.next();
    if (keywords.contains(word)) 
      frequencyData.put(word, getCount(word, frequencyData) + 1);
  }
  return frequencyData;
}

private static void printAllCounts(Map<String, Integer> frequencyData) {
  System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------");
  System.out.println(" Occurrences Word");
  for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> e : frequencyData.entrySet())
    System.out.printf("%15d %s\n", e.getValue(), e.getKey());
  System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------");
}

private static int getCount(String word, Map<String, Integer> frequencyData) {
    return frequencyData.containsKey(word)? frequencyData.get(word) : 0;
}

private static Set<String> loadKeywords(String fname) 
throws FileNotFoundException 
{
  final Set<String> result = new HashSet<String>();
  for (Scanner s = new Scanner(new FileReader(fname)); s.hasNext();) 
    result.add(s.next());
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marko, My appologies. I did not include what I had attempted to do with an Input StreamReader to try and handle the keyword.txt file, because it was a mess and did not function at all. Thanks you for the code you provided, much appreciated and it works exactly as I was trying to do.

Comment: Glad to help. Just please, [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer (as a matter of StackOverflow etiquette).